# Oracle not prompting to change the password when password is expired

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, database-administration

When account_status is expired usually it will prompt to change the password of the next login, But here it throws the below error and closing while connecting through PL/SQL and sqlplus tool.

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small. 
ORA-06512: at line 8 
ORA-28001: the password has expired

When i try to connect from server. It is prompting to change the password.  What may be the error. FYI-Account_status is not locked.

How to make prompting to change the password in Pl/SQL developer or toad or sqlplus tool when account_status is in expired state?

Comment: Is there some sort of logon trigger thats getting called? since it indicates its a pl/sql error ? Also there could a trigger to log errors that could cause the same issue as well...

Answer (score 0):

There could be an error in the password verification function.  I made this exact same mistake a few weeks ago and effectively locked people out of their account.

Find your password verification function with this query:

```
select * from dba_profiles where resource_name = 'PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION';
```

Look at this source with this query:

```
select * from dba_source where name = '<name from above query>';
```

Most password verification functions have arrays at the top that hold the sets of characters.  There's probably a variable declaration like this at
 line 8:

```
special_character_array varchar2(10) := '!@#$%^&*()';
```

For some reason most people only choose a few of the most common special characters.  Then people are not able to change their password when they use a less common character.

To fix this, a DBA might add more characters to the list.  Here's a more complete list of all special characters on a typical US English keyboard:

```
special_character_array varchar2(10) := '`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:''",<.>/?';
```

The mistake was adding more characters but not increasing the size of `varchar2(10)` to `varchar2(31)`.  (Or plan for the worst make it `varchar2(4000)`.)  This would cause the error "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small."

If this is the problem you'll need to be logged in as SYSDBA to recompile the password verification function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jon Heller for good explanation.

I found that the error is caused by some log trigger created by us. As you mentioned, increasing the size of varchar2(100) for particular variable solved this issue. Now it's prompting to change the password when account status is expired for the user.